# Refraction of light with different wavelengths

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, speed-of-light, refraction, dispersion

A red light and blue light enter a rectangular glass block normal to its surface at the same time. Strictly speaking, after passing through the block, which pulse exits first?
Should I consider their paths inside glass slab to be same as the lights are entering normal to the surface?

Comment: Please read the “Refractive index” article in wikipedia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll go read about the topic to be sure, but since the red and blue pulse (I assume they're visible light) are interacting differently in the glass (I assume a linear and isotropic crystal here) (different diffraction indices, v=$\omega$/k=c/n), and all is linked to the wavelenght/frequency combined with the permeability (in other words,interaction) one can expect that the red light, which interract less with the médium than blue, will come out first. Hope it helps, cheers

Comment: Thanks Laurier, that's quite helpful. I had similar thoughts on this problem and with your solution, my concept is clear.